# Error: Flash driver function execute error Program Download Failed?

Tags: runtime-error, stm32f0, coocox

I was working with stm32 board. While debugging, I am getting this error possibly error is in rasing flash

> C:\CooCox\CoIDE>"C:/CooCox/CoIDE/bin\coflash.exe" program STM32F051R8
>   "D:/Programs/STM/blinker/blinkLeds/Debug/bin/blinkLeds.elf"
>   --adapter-name=ST-Link --port=SWD --adapter-clk=1000000 --erase=affected --reset=SYSRESETREQ --driver="C:/CooCox/CoIDE/flash/STM32F05xx_64.elf"   Erase:     Failed Error: Flash driver function execute error Program Download Failed !

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue with the IDE or with the way you upload code onto the board as suggested in this forum : http://www.coocox.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4736&f=2

Hope this helps.